# Kabira Crosswords: A MtG Crossword

Tags: knowledge, crosswords, magic-the-gathering

I wanted to post a second MtG puzzle that's a bit more lighthearted and different than the usual challenges. Rules knowledge isn't required here, just card knowledge. And I made sure to use cards that are relatively iconic and well known or new enough that newer players should have no problem identifying the cards used (no random Kamigawa commons)

It's an MtG themed crossword! Every entry is a more or less a silly pun/variation of a card name (the clues describe the variation, not the original card name). They won't be more than a few letters off, and usually rhyme with the original card name. The letter additions/substitutions/replacements will be made to only word of the card name (with slight exception for 23 Across). Puncuation and spaces are omitted. For example, "Erase Korean City" would be 'Remove Seoul' instead of 'Remove Soul'

I couldn't get the inline image to resize larger for clearer numbers, but you can open it in new tab to view it in original size.

[image]

### Horizontal

$4$. Feeble praetor
$5$. Circus performer's vehicle
$6$. Shocking accessory
$7$. Praetor's map
$8$. Seraph of earth
$9$. Bird that facilitates hookups
$12$. Draw an oval!
$13$. Colossus of dark ages
$16$. Pregnant phyrexian fish
$18$. Cutlery with discipline
$19$. Leaky vessel fix
$21$. Most holy texts
$22$. Silent gait
$23$. Tales of farm equipment
$24$. Baptism
$25$. Archaic nuclear experiments
$26$. Magic locomotive
$27$. Church's basins
$28$. Crypt weapon
$29$. Hotdog vending phyrexian
$30$. Serpentine commander-in-chief

### Vertical

$1$. Elemental notes
$2$. Bald fire-breather
$3$. Brainfart's cousin
$10$. Memory therapist
$11$. Artificer's treasury
$14$. Last step on the ladder to nothingness
$15$. Falling pastries
$17$. Downfall of a noble
$20$. Edible flower
$22$. Aquatic jump

Comment: It's been a day since this was posted, so I wanted to open up an opportunity for hints for those having trouble with a particular clue. For anyone stuck on one or 2 clues, feel free to comment below for an additional hint

Answer (score 1):

Partial:

Horizontal

> 5: Juggler's Copter (Smuggler's Copter)
>  6: Lightning Belt (Lightning Bolt)
>  8: Terra Angel (Serra Angel)
>  9: Tinder Fowl? (Tinder Wall)
>  12: Elliptic Command (Cryptic Command)
>  13: Medieval Titan (Primeval Titan)
>  22: Mime Walk (Time Walk)
>  23: Tractor Fiction (Fact or Fiction)
>  27: Bath of God (Wrath of God)(doesn't actually come close to fitting)
>  28: Tomb Blade (Doom Blade)

Vertical

> 2: Shaven Dragon (Shivan Dragon)
>  11: Cable Coffers? (Cabal Coffers)
>  20: Snack Lotus? (Black Lotus)
>  22: Manta Vault? (Mana Vault)